# Mocha + Webpack + Typescript (React): Error cannot find module (typescript component)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, mocha.js, babeljs

I am migrating a react app to use typescript. I have added a typescript component and imported in another react component. The app compiles and runs smoothly. However when I run tests `yarn test` then Mocha cannot locate my typescript component:

```
Error: Cannot find module './manage_new/TypescriptFile'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dan/Documents/my-ui/src/ui/main/Modal.jsx:7:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at loader (/home/dan/Documents/my-ui/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .jsx] (/home/dan/Documents/my-ui/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)...
```

The error comes where I import the typescript component `import { TypescriptFile } from './manage_new/TypescriptFile'` . A temp turn-around solution is import using extension: `'./manage_new/TypescriptFile.tsx` which WORKS. However, it's not the ideal way. I wanted to get it working using usual import.

The webpack.config.babel.js file has some entries like:

```
resolve: {
extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json'],
alias: getAlias(),
},
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      // options: ### to fully enable hot load / HMR, we use settings from package.json: babel.presets ###
    },
    exclude: /node_modules/
  },
 {
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'ts-loader',
    },
    exclude: /node_modules/
  }
]}
```

The tsconfig.json has entries:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"outDir": "./dist/",
"baseUrl": "src/",
"noImplicitAny": true,
"module": "es6",
"target": "es6",
"jsx": "react",
"allowJs": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"moduleResolution": "node",
"strictNullChecks": true
  },
"include": [
"./src/**/*"
]
```

The command I run is:

```
yarn run cross-env NODE_PATH=./src BABEL_ENV=test node --inspect node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --compilers jsx:babel-register --require source-map-support/register -r mock-local-storage -r ./ui-test.helper.js "src/**/*.test@(.js|.jsx)" --reporter progress
```

It would be great if anyone could help me figure this out so that I can get Mocha correctly locate my Typescript components. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I saw a similar issue, and I fixed it by adding `--require ts-node/register`. So code below might work for you, though I haven't tested it on react

```sh
npx mocha --require ts-node/register --require esm src/**/*.spec.ts
```

Or in `package.json` scripts (both options work, choose whichever you like):

```json
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha -r esm -r ts-node/register src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "test-ts": "ts-mocha -r esm -p tsconfig.json src/**/*.spec.ts"
}
```

And don't forget to add `esm` to `devDependencies`:

```
npm install --save-dev esm
```

so in package.json it is gonna be

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "esm": "^3.2.25"
}
```